# presentModalViewController causes sigabrt inside UINavigationController in IOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, sigabrt

Now, at the moment my application consists of a UINavigationController, which then passes (via a button) to a normal UIViewController, which then uses presentModalViewController to load another UIViewController (without the nav bar.)

If I try running the program in the IOS 6.1 simulator, this works perfectly fine. However, if I instead try running it in the IOS 5.1 simulator, I get a sigabrt error when I call presentModalViewController. This code worked before I introduced the UINavigationController, but I have no idea what's causing the error now.

Possibly relevant details:

Both the UINavigationController and the first UIViewController work via the use of storyboards. However, the second UIViewController (the one I'm passing to) I'm using loads via a .xib file.

The code for the actual pass is below.

```
    AllViewController* controller = [[AllViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AllViewController"] bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    //And now for the swap
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And the console's output for the error is this:

```
2013-05-17 13:38:49.934 Practice Solutions[4372:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1627022 0xf9fcd6 0x15cfa48 0x15cf9b9 0x4234a3 0x42367b 0x423383 0x32316d 0x1c91fc 0x1c9779 0x1c999b 0x1d29bc 0x1cd818 0x3e9565 0x1d0857 0x1d09bc 0x1d09fc 0x4d7e 0x1628e99 0x10514e 0x1050e6 0x1abade 0x1abfa7 0x1ab266 0x12a3c0 0x12a5e6 0x110dc4 0x104634 0x17baef5 0x15fb195 0x155fff2 0x155e8da 0x155dd84 0x155dc9b 0x17b97d8 0x17b988a 0x102626 0x274d 0x2675)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

If anyone could help with this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this bit of code `initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AllViewController"]bundle: nil]` can be shortened down to `initWithNibName:@"AllViewController" bundle:nil]`

Comment: When you get an error like this, please do some searching on key elements of the error before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your using constraints in Interface Builder and it only works for iOS 6, so you need to turn them off in IB.